# python limpeza de dados crus manualmente

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data_r = open('rosalind_gc.txt', 'r')
data_r1 = data_r.readlines()
data_r2 = []
data_r3 = []
#tirar os \n do texto
for i in data_r1:
    data_r2.append(i.rstrip())
data_index = []
#filtrar Rosalind em index --done
for i in data_r2:
    if 'Rosalind' in i:
        data_index.append(data_r2.index(i))
#criar dicts com rosalind
for linha in data_r2:
    linha_index = data_r2.index(linha) 
    if linha_index in data_index: # só acontece nas linhas == Rosalind
        out_index = linha_index + 1
        data_r3.append({linha:''})
#sequenciar cadeia de dados
```

to tentando sequenciar manualmente os dados, pra fazer um dicionário que retorn as espécies de Rosalind com sua respectiva sequência, mas sempre fica sem valor na última chave do dicionário.

aqui está um exemplo de dataset abreviado:
(tal como vem no arquivo txt)

> Rosalind_6404
>   CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGAATAGCCAGAACCGTTTCTCTGAGGCTTCCGGCCTTCCC
>   TCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG
>   Rosalind_5959
>   CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCAGGCGCTCCGCCGAAGGTCT
>   ATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC
>   Rosalind_0808
>   CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGAC
>   TGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que seu arquivo de entrada seja algo como:

```
Rosalind_6404 CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGAATAGCCAGAACCGTTTCTCTGAGGCTTCCGGCCTTCCC TCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG
Rosalind_5959 CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCAGGCGCTCCGCCGAAGGTCT ATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC
Rosalind_0808 CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGAC TGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT
```

Segue um exemplo de código comentado capaz de resolver o seu problema:

```
import pandas as pd

registros = []

# Abre arquivo texto para leitura
with open('rosalind_gc.txt') as arquivo:

    # Para cada linha no arquivo...
    for linha in arquivo:

        # Remove o(s) caractere(s) de final de linha
        linha = linha.rstrip()

        # Quebra a linha em dois campos
        # usando espaco como separador
        registro = linha.split(' ', 1)

        # Verifica se a linha foi quebrada corretamente
        if len(registro) == 2:

            # Monta dicionario com os dois campos lidos
            dicionario = {
                'nome_especie': registro[0],
                'sequencia': registro[1]
            }

            # Adiciona dicionario na lista de registros
            registros.append(dicionario)

# Converte lista de dicionarios
# em um data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(registros)

# Exibe data frame
print(df)
```

Saída:

```
    nome_especie                                          sequencia
0  Rosalind_6404  CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGAATAGCCAGAACCGTTTCTCTGAGG...
1  Rosalind_5959  CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCAGGCGC...
2  Rosalind_0808  CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTC...
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SmugSnowMultithreading)

Answer (score 0):

Oi, meu amigo.

Quando você usa uma linguagem, você tem que estar habituado aos recursos dela.

Tente entender como usar o Python e, especificamente, a biblioteca Pandas. Muito poderosa. O Python foi criado, entre outras coisas, para ser altamente produtivo.

Vamos lá. Não gosto de enrolar. Sua solução está abaixo:

```
dados_lista = []

dados = open('SEU_ARQUIVO_AQUI', 'r').readlines()

for um_dado in dados:
    nome, sequencia_dna = um_dado.split(' ', 1)

    dados_lista.append({'nome' : nome, 'sequencia_dna' : sequencia_dna})

df = pd.DataFrame(dados_lista)
```

O df já é o DataFrame que contém todos os seus dados, do jeito que você precisa.

O resultado pra mim ficou como abaixo, usando os dados que você mandou na mensagem.

[image: Resultado no Ambiente Jupyter usado por mim aqui.]

Espero ter ajudado.

Grande abraço.